# pgfplots: tikzpicture within tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, tikz-styles

I like to use `tikz` nodes to position plots next to each other.
However in the following MWE the axis seem to be shifted to the left.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=.4\linewidth] (A) {%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x^2 - x +4};                  
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
    };

    \node[text width=.4\linewidth,anchor = north] (B) at (A.south) {%   
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x^2 - x +4};                  
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
    };  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need `text width=.4\linewidth` ? Because if I remove it, the plots look fine.

Comment: I scaled the plots this way, but at the moment I cannot think about a reason why I should not do this directly at the axis. If you provide an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key `text width=.4\linewidth` is inherited by `yticklabel style` and `xticklabel style`. That is why the tick labels appear shifted. Removing the unnecessary key from the nodes fixes this issue.

[image: pgfplots]

Answer (score 1):

Every `tikzpicture` is considered like a single `char` and you don't need to include them in external `tikzpictures` to place them, you could use simple `tabluar` or just an empty line like in following example.

If you need to fix plot dimensions, `width` and `height axis'` will also help you.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=.4\linewidth]
            \addplot {x^2 - x +4};                  
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}

            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=.4\linewidth]
            \addplot {x^2 - x +4};                  
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]